# Having not Written/not Having Written

Tags: word-order

Could you, too, say which is correct and which is quite wrong?

1. Not having written his book, Mr. George was mercilessly massacred;
2. Having not written his book, Mr. George was mercilessly massacred.

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of ["Having not" vs "not having"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119423/191178), but the answers there are not great.

Comment: I can find a lot of discussion elsewhere but both seem OK; certainly no grounds to prefer one over the other: https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/not-having-or-having-not.139885/ https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/having-not-not-having https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/not-having-having-not-previewed-the-lesson.2045285/ https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/4p277v/having_not_vs_not_having/

Comment: A massacre is the killing of _many_ people - can one person be massacred?

Comment: They're both wrong because it's impossible to tell what either one means. Was he massacred **because** he wrote/didn't write his/some other book? Is he still alive? Were the assailants caught? Why would anyone write this way?